# How to install sciDAVis on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gsl, ubuntu-18.04

Installing the sciDAVis .deb file on Ubuntu 18.04 fails due to two unfound dependencies. How do I install these dependencies?

I'm using the scidavis_1.D23_amd64.deb installation file.

Here's the failed installation report:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i scidavis_1.D23_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package scidavis.
(Reading database ... 406985 files and directories currently 
installed.)
Preparing to unpack scidavis_1.D23_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking scidavis (1.D23) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of scidavis:
 scidavis depends on libgsl2; however:
  Package libgsl2 is not installed.
 scidavis depends on libqwtplot3d-qt4-0v5 (>= 0.2.7); however:
  Package libqwtplot3d-qt4-0v5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package scidavis (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) 
...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 scidavis
```

I've tried `sudo apt install libgsl2` which fails with the message

```
Package libgsl2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libgslcblas0:i386 libgslcblas0
```

libgslcblas0 is already installed on my system, and apt reports that it is the latest version.

Likewise, libqwtplot3d-qt4-0v5 is not available for apt to install.

Is there a solution? Or will sciDAVis not yet run on 18.04?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I tried a different way to install sciDAVis: adding the repository and key and then using apt to install. This method got me a little further, as now sciDAVis appears in the Ubuntu applications. However, when I try to run sciDAVis, I now receive the message `scidavis: error while loading shared libraries: libqwtplot3d.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`  I've found the file  libqwtplot3d.so.0 on my machine in /usr/lib64, so I copied it to /usr/share/scidavis, but I still receive the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick really.

```
sudo apt install -fy
```

That is after the `dpkg` command you put up. The above command gets the missing bits together.

Comment: Well, that -fy switch was magic. Thanks!  Unfortunately, now when I run scidavis, I receive an error: `$ scidavis
scidavis: error while loading shared libraries: libqwtplot3d.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Looks like the libqwtplot3d.so.0 problem is a problem with scidavis, not with the apt installation problem I was having before. Thanks for the help. I'll take the issue up with scidavis on their sourceforge page.

Comment: so what happens, if you go to `/usr/lib` and put a sym link there:  
`sudo ln -s libqwtplot3d-qt5.so.0 libqwtplot3d.so.0`

Comment: Turns out to be a known bug with sciDAVis.  According to the devs, the work-around is to edit the file `/etc/ld.so.conf` by adding a line `/etc/lib64`.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone wants to install the latest SciDAVis version on Linux but the distribution used does not provide it officially, then the best way is to take a look at [[1](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Ahpcoder1&package=scidavis)] in order to see if the distribution used is supported ([[1](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Ahpcoder1&package=scidavis)] is a repository at OpenSUSE Build Service maintained by Russell Standish, a SciDAVis developer). If your distro is listed there click on its logo and then on the link named "Add repository manually". So follow the instructions for the version you have installed in your computer.

As an example, to install SciDAVis 1.D23 on (K/X)Ubuntu 18.04 do:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/hpcoder1/xUbuntu_18.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:hpcoder1.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scidavis
```

An information that is not in [[1](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Ahpcoder1&package=scidavis)]: based on my own experiences, if the installation using the procedure above fails, then try to uninstall the SciDAVis deps¹ before run "sudo apt-get install scidavis"

¹ libmuparser*, libqwt*, libqwtplot3d*

Answer (score 0):

**To install Scidavis in Ubuntu 18.04 run the following:**

*sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/hpcoder1/xUbuntu_18.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:hpcoder1.list"*

You can add the repository key to apt. Keep in mind that the owner of the key may distribute updates, packages and repositories that your system will trust (more information). To add the key, run:

*wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:hpcoder1/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key -O Release.key*

*sudo apt-key add - < Release.key*

*sudo apt-get update*

*sudo apt-get install scidavis*

For further details please visit 
https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=home%3Ahpcoder1&package=scidavis

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ubuntu 18.04 use this:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/hpcoder1/xUbuntu_18.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:hpcoder1.list"

wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:hpcoder1/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key -O Release.key

sudo apt-key add - < Release.key

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install scidavis
```

For xUbuntu 14.04 to xUbuntu 19.04 visit this page:
https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=home%3Ahpcoder1&package=scidavis

Comment: Right now I have a trouble with the installation, but I'm trying with the notes in:  SciDAVis - Installation Notes - SourceForge

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe" 
>>/etc/apt/sources.list 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scidavis
```

Comment: Mixing repositories for Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 18.04 can cause package management issues such as unmet dependencies and broken packages.